# Joomla Multiple Domain names for one Joomla Install

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am using this article here to have two domains names point to the same Joomla install, with one having a different home page.

http://docs.joomla.org/Multiple_Domains_and_Web_Sites_in_a_single_Joomla!_installation
(option 2)

The sites open okay, and the second domain even goes to the correct landing page.  The issue is that when on the second domain, all menu links open in a new window(they are relative links, but in the html it is adding "target=_blank")  and i am not sure why, or how to stop it.

All the menu links properly open in the parent window when on the primary domain.

here are the two live links:

http://www.hustoninsurance.com/
http://tiffinhealthexchange.com/

Thanks in advance.
Running Joomla 3.0

Comment: What's the name of the Google Analytics plugin/module that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the page source of tiffinhealth, and there is a function specialtrack() which is adding the target="_blank"

```
var specialtrack = new (function() {
[...]
var initialize = function() {
    var links = document.links;

    for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
        var match = links[i].pathname.match(whitelist);
        var match_links = links[i].href.match(domain);
        var match_void = links[i].href.match('javascript:void');
        if (typeof match_void == 'undefined' || match_void == null) {
            if (typeof match !== 'undefined' && match !== null) {
                links[i].addEventListener('click',trackpush_downloads,false);
                links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');                                  
            }else if (typeof match_links == 'undefined' || match_links == null) {
                links[i].addEventListener('click',trackpush_links,false);
                links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');                                  
            }
        }           
    }   
};
```

The line `links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');` is the one to blame for adding the target="_blank"; you should investigate with the developer or try to use an alternative solution to serve your purpose; maybe you could also avoid using two tracking on the same page.

Also, in your source you have plenty of absolute urls including the domain name: make sure this is consistent across the two domains otherwise page cache will eventually contain inconsistencies:

```
   <a href="http://www.hustoninsurance.com/images/Showcases/Locations/99 Ashwood Rd/Group.png">
   <img src="http://tiffinhealthexchange.com/images/Showcases/Locations/99 Ashwood Rd/Group.png" alt="Group.png"/></a>
```